# elementary OS freya Panel Disappear

Tags: wingpanel, updates

Just now i got an Notification Update. so i installed it after that i reboot my PC then the panel disappear you can see at this picture. Any idea Please???

[image: Panel disappear]

and here output of `apt-cache policy indicator-synapse`

```
indicator-synapse:
  Installed: 0.525-0~trusty~NoobsLab.com
  Candidate: 0.525-0~trusty~NoobsLab.com
     Version table:
       *** 0.525-0~trusty~NoobsLab.com 0
             500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
             100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
              0~529-0~ubuntu14.04.1 0
              500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/unstable-upstream/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Open terminal using `win+ t` , (I mean by using shortcut), [edit] post and add output of `apt-cache policy indicator-synapse`